# How do I write c# code that detects a proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, detect

I need to be able to detect if navigating to a particular URL requires hitting a proxy server.  Some ideas as well as c# (or Java) code would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time
DTM

Comment: When you say navigating, what do you mean? Are you trying to build a tool that will hit a given URL and test to see if you are routed through a proxy?

Comment: Precisely.  I just want to build a utility that will tell me "Hey in order to reach this URL, we had to send it through a proxy".

Comment: The bypass list is a property of the proxy configuration.  WebProxy.BypassList property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx) gives you access to the proxy, and then you can feed your URL to `GetProxy()` and see what it returns:

`Console.WriteLine(WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com")));`

Comment: That tells you which proxy is configured.  It doesn't tell you whether direct connections (bypassing the proxy) will work.